# HTTPS on localhost not working

Tags: apache, ssl

I just followed the steps for using SSL on localhost: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

But when i access https://localhost, i get this message:

> Page Web inaccessible
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm using Apache2 with Ubuntu trusty on Vagrant.

Let me know if you want more informations.

Thank's

Comment: What sense is there behind using https on an internal loopback network interface inside a system?

Comment: I use it to connect to a remote OpenID server.

Comment: `https://localhost` certainly is not the connection to a remote system. Maybe some logic inside your local http server make a connection to a remote system, but that is separate.

Comment: I make a request from https://localhost -> remote system.

Comment: As said: `https://localhost` does _not_ connect to a remote system. So why do you want to use https there? and as said before: if some server side logic make a remote connection that is fine and probably using https _in that connection_ makes sense. But that has nothing to do with `https://localhost`. And you do not need a certificate for that, since in that case your server is the client.

Answer (score 2):

There are three possibilities about this message:

- Your self-signed certificate is invalid for some reason. 
  Please see your Apache error log.
- Your Apache SSL/TLS protocols do not match with those of your browser.
  Try something like the following from a command prompt: `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443` to test the SSL/TLS connection. Please update your question with the output.
- May be there is a firewall between your browser and your Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to Apache performing a reverse DNS lookup on the URL - the result of which does not match any of your PC's aliases.

Try `https://127.0.0.1` or `https://<hostname>`.